# How to catch node.js http error on nonexistent host?

Tags: http, node.js, error-handling

when I'm trying to use the `http` module to access nonexistent host, like this:

```
requestToRemote = http.createClient(80, 'fjasdfhasdkfj.vvvxcz').request(
    method,
    path,
    headers
);
```

But I get the following error:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT
    at errnoException (dns.js:31:11)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:140:16)
```

I'd like to catch this error, so I've tried try/catch and setting the error listeners of a bunch of request properties, but none of if worked. How can I catch the error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like the error is thrown from `http.Client`, not the request. How about something like:

```
var site = http.createClient(80, host);
site.on('error', function(err) {
    sys.debug('unable to connect to ' + host);
});
var requestToRemote = site.request(...);
```

FYI, `http.createClient` has been deprecated -- the following should work using the get convenience method:

```
http.get({host: host}, function(res) {
    ...
}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Comment: How do I use the `res` value in the callback to see what the text of the response is?

Comment: This solves not the problem of catching noexistent host, or dns resolution problem. `the try catch` option works not too.

Answer (score -1):

you could try and resolve the host using the dns module before running your code.

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/dns.html#dns.resolve

Comment: This is not a good solution, as it would then involve resolving the hostname twice.  Even when cached, there is still a small penalty that can multiply quickly, depending on the needs of your app.  Sure, you could then use the network address instead of hostname when you make the request, but then you have to handle request headers that specify the host yourself.